# Underline div based on its content

Tags: css

I have a text block that spans multiple lines.

I want to underline the text block as a whole based on the longest line of text.

The width of the text block is set to auto and I don't want to set a fixed width because I have different blocks of text that need this same underlining.

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<p>first line of test text which is long enough to stretch onto a second line becausealloicioudsiscool hello line hello line hello line hello line hello. prettysuperlongline long line becausealloicioudsiscool</p>
```

Though the snippet may look okay at the size you are seeing, I took a picture of the issue I am having and pasted it below.

`Display:inline-block;` works well when I don't have long words, but if I have a long word like "superlongline", it makes the div be full width and the word drops down to the next line.

The `border-bottom` ends up going the full width of the div when the content doesn't actually reach the end of the div.

[image]
Here is a picture of one of the text blocks I'm looking to underline. I want it to stop at the end of "Mountain", but it extends a bit past it because of what I mentioned above. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS so we know what's happening.

Comment: Your example shows the shorter line underlined. Do you actually want the last line underlined?

Comment: Why not just set a bottom border for the text block?

Comment: You can probably do it easily using flexbox, but you didn't show us any HTML or anything so  why should we guess the HTML structure?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/141/

Comment: Based on @uom-pgregorio example, here's a multiline of how it should work http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/142/

Comment: I will post my css now, but I updated your fiddle to show you what I'm talking about http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/146/ @AlonEitan

Comment: The line under the block is as long as the longest text. What's the problem?

Comment: @HeinzSchilling posted an image of what I'm seeing. Maybe our browser sizes are different or something

Comment: @Anthony its been tried

Comment: It looks like it is doing what you want it to? Inline-block means the heading will be as wide as the content inside of it, and the border-bottom will go the width of the heading...so I'm a bit at a loss of how what else you are wanting for it?

Comment: @PaigeMeinke.  You'll notice in my question what I am looking to do is underline a text block. I am looking for the underline to span the longest line of text in the block. What you're seeing is the correct behavior of what youre explaining, however it is not the solution for the problem I am trying to solve which is why I am asking a question.

Comment: ahh okay, i get it now, after looking at your image again. Because of the long words, it goes to the next line but it looks like it's full width underline...gotchya. Let me think a bit. Do you mind if I slightly edit your question to be a bit clearer for others to understand?

Comment: sure that would be great actually. thanks for your help @PaigeMeinke